# jsPDF Error: autoTable is not a function in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, pdf, frontend, sapui5

I am using the jsPDF library for converting a table into a PDF file.
The current code that I have used is giving off an error, that autoTable is not a function.
Here is the code.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/util/Export",
    "sap/ui/core/util/ExportTypeCSV"
],

    function (Controller, JSONModel, Export, ExportTypeCSV) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("c.g.modalproject1.controller.Root", {
            onInit: function () {

                var oModel1 = new JSONModel("./model/vegetableDataJSON.json");
                this.getView().setModel(oModel1, "veg");
                console.log("data : ", oModel1);

            },

            openDialog1: function () {
                if (!this.pdialog1) {
                    this.pdialog1 = this.loadFragment({
                        name: "c.g.modalproject1.fragments.mTables"
                    });
                }
                this.pdialog1.then(function (oDialog) {
                    oDialog.open();
                })
                new sap.m.MessageToast.show("Table Loaded");
            },

            closeDialog: function () {
                this.byId("newDialog1").close();
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Table closed ! ");

                // var vegTable = this.getView().byId("vegiesMTable");
                // vegTable.setGrowing(false);
                // vegTable.setGrowingScrollToLoad(false);

            },

            downloadCSV: function () {
                // Show a toast message to indicate that the file is downloading
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Downloading Excel..");
                // Create a new Export object with the specified export type and options
                var oExport = new Export({
                    exportType: new ExportTypeCSV({
                        separatorChar: ","
                    }),
                    models: this.getView().getModel("veg"),
                    rows: {
                        path: "/vegetablesRootNode"
                    },
                    columns: [{
                        name: "Title",
                        template: {
                            content: "{title}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Type",
                        template: {
                            content: "{type}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Description",
                        template: {
                            content: "{description}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Price",
                        template: {
                            content: "{price}"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Rating",
                        template: {
                            content: "{rating}"
                        }
                    }]
                });
                // Save the file and handle any errors that may occur
                oExport.saveFile().catch(function (oError) {
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error when downloading data. Browser might not be supported!\n\n" + oError);
                }).then(function () {
                    // Destroy the export object
                    oExport.destroy();
                });
            },

            downloadPDF:function()
            {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Downloading into PDF started !");
                var oModel2 = this.getView().getModel("veg");
                console.log("check data = ", oModel2);

                var oColumns = ["Title","Type","Description","Price","Rating"];

                var oRows = [];
                oRows = oModel2.oData.vegetablesRootNode;
                console.log(oColumns);
                console.log(oRows);

                //var pdfDoc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
                var pdfDoc = new jsPDF();

                pdfDoc.text(20, 20, "Vegetables Table");
                pdfDoc.autoTable(oRows, oColumns);

                pdfDoc.save("test.pdf");

                //pdfDoc.output("save","t.pdf");
            }

        });
    });
```

The last function is the code that runs to save the table data into PDF.
Can you please help.

These are the files that are included in my project folder.

[Manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7wk1.png)

Adding just text, and most of the functionality that is available (via methods) from jsPDF works fine. I have created PDFs with just text from this app as well.
It works fine for adding text and downloads fine. But for Table data, it doesnt work.

I tried various ways but didn't get to solve it at all.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jspdf-autotable/info: > _"AutoTable is an extension for the popular jsPDF library which adds useful functionality for exporting tables in PDF format"_ ... Have you installed https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable?

Comment: Hi, I am using the recent version of jsPDF. I have kept all the files (jsPDF, jspdf-autotable, cell, FileSaver) in a folder and already made it aware to the app, via the manifest file.

Comment: @SAPASFlash The `manifest.json` section `/sap.ui5/resources/js` is **deprecated** since UI5 1.94. Please do not rely on `/js`. You need other ways of integrating jsPDF and its plugins in UI5. Unfortunately, I have no experience with jsPDF

Comment: @Boghyon Hoffmann I am using 1.109.3 so what is a better way to load external JS files to use in UI5 ? Thank you.

Comment: @SAPASFlash depth1 already gave a perfect answer. :)

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann yes, I have already implemented it with some custom modification to the data and it works just nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to make a POC with this library and it works :-)

1. Configure the framework so that it can load the libraries

   ```js
   sap.ui.loader.config({
     // activate real async loading and module definitions
     async: true,

     // load thirparty from e.g. CDN
     paths: {
       "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDF": "https://unpkg.com/jspdf@2.5.1/dist/jspdf.umd.min",
       "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDFautoTable": "https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.5.28/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable"
     },

     // provide dependency and export metadata for non-UI5 modules
     shim: {
       "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDF": {
         amd: true,
         exports: "jspdf" // name of the global variable under which jsPDF exports its module value
       },
       "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDFautoTable": {
         amd: true,
         exports: "jspdf",
         deps: [ "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDF" ]
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   You can put that code on top on your `my.project.Component`.
   Idea is to configure the framework to load libraries from CDN as AMD module with dependencies.

   - [API reference: `sap.ui.loader.config`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.loader%23methods/sap.ui.loader.config)
   - Regarding `shim`: see section ["**Third Party Modules**" at `sap.ui.define`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui%23methods/sap.ui.define).
2. Loads and consumes libraries:

   ```
   sap.ui.define([ // or sap.ui.require
     // ...
     "my/project/thirdparty/jsPDFautoTable"
   ], function (/*...,*/jsPDFautoTable) {
     // ...
     var doc = new jsPDFautoTable.jsPDF();
     doc.autoTable({ html: "#my-table" });
     doc.save("table.pdf");
     // ...
   });
   ```

Either with `sap.ui.define` or `sap.ui.require` to load the library on the fly when needed.

Comment: Hi, it worked. Thanks. I still need to custom create another array from the model array that should contain values of the keys only. Thanks again. I didn't knew about loading libraries in this way.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how you used the jsPDFautoTable.jsPDF() or from which CDN File can we simply import jsPDF directly and then use it.

Comment: In conifg.paths you tell the ui5 framework to map the module named "tiers/jsPDF" to the remote module https://unpkg.com/jspdf@2.5.1/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js (omit the . js in the path ) and if you want another version or another file or from another vendor, write it here.
Then, in the shim part, you indicate which object you want to export from the module thus imported.

after I'm not sure I understand maybe you want me to post the poc?