# How to avoid own D3 library being overwritten when loading other FLP apps?

Tags: d3.js, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am developing a custom Fiori app (let's call it App1) that uses the thirdparty library *D3*. I needed the newer version (7.5.0) since the existing `sap/ui/thirdparty/d3`, that is bundled with OpenUI5, is only at 3.4.12. I did:

1. Download the `d3.js` with version 7.5.0.
2. Save it in my project folder:

   [image]
3. Add the resource to my `manifest.json`:

   ```json
   "resources": {
     "js": [
       { "uri": "library/d3.js" }
     ]
   }
   ```

At first loading of the application, everything works fine. I am able to use version 7.5.0. But when I switch between Fiori apps from the SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP), the D3 library gets overwritten by version 3.4.12.

I tried to load the `d3.js` version 7.5.0 again when I reopen the App1, but it does not take effect.

How can I retain my D3 version to 7.5.0 even when I navigate to other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `manifest.json` section `/sap.ui5/resources/js` is deprecated. Remove the section.
2. Instead, call the [`sap.ui.loader.config`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.loader#methods/sap.ui.loader.config) API accordingly:

   - with your own namespace in the `shim` settings
   - and **before** the d3 is loaded, e.g., either before `this.getRouter().initialize()` or even before declaring the UIComponent's list of dependencies in your `Component.js`.

Here is an example with more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75177939/5846045.

Comment: This helped me with my issue. Thank you very much!